# Finding generic type in parallel hierarchies of generic types

Tags: java, generics

Imagine I have 3 rules : `Rule<A>`, `Rule<B>`, `Rule<C>`
Same I have 3 datasources : `Datasource<A>`, `Datasource<B>`, `Datasource<C>`

If I have a list of rules : `List<Rule<?>>`
and I do a stream : `ruleList.stream().map(rule -> ...)`

In the lambda function, I would like to call the datasource with same generic type than rule. For example :

```
ruleList.stream().map(rule -> {
   Class<T> ruleType = ... // Class<A>, Class<B> or Class<C>
   Datasource<T> datasource = datasourceResolver.resolve(ruleType); // Datasource<A>, Datasource<B> or Datasource<C>
   return datasource.doSomething();
})
```

What would be the code to retrieve the `ruleType` and the code of `datasourceResolver` ?

Comment: You need to explain how you are getting `ruleType`.

Comment: @tgdavies that's part of the question, I want to get `ruleType` but I do not know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of type erasure you'll need to take Rule and DataSource together (not logical) or:

```
class Rule<T> {
    public final Class<T> type;
    protected Rule(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

private Map<Class<?>, DataSource<?>> dataSourcesByType = New HashMap<>();
```

Now you can register DataSources by type

```
Class<?> ruleType = rule.type;
DataSource<?> ds = dataSourcesByType.get(ruleType);
```

You'll notice `<?>`, especially that `ds` cannot be more specific.

That could hint at alternative method overrides for cases A, B, C. A more type safe Map getter

```
public <X> DataSource<X> get(Class<X> type)
```